# How do I subtract from every second[i][1] element in a 2d array?

Tags: python

Here is my 2d array:

```
[['P1', 27], ['P2', 44], ['P3', 65], ['P4', 51], ['P5', 31], ['P6', 18], ['P7', 33]]
```

I have created a loop to attach each appropriate label to its corresponding value within this 2d array. At the end of the loop I would like to subtract every value by a different number.

For example: if I wanted to subtract the values by 5

```
[['P1', 22], ['P2', 39], ['P3', 60], ['P4', 46], ['P5', 26], ['P6', 13], ['P7', 28]]
```

How do I do this while the array has both a str type and int?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a simple job for a list comprehension:

```
>>> L = [['P1', 27], ['P2', 44], ['P3', 65], ['P4', 51], ['P5', 31], ['P6', 18], ['P7', 33]]
>>> [[s, n - 5] for s, n in L]
[['P1', 22], ['P2', 39], ['P3', 60], ['P4', 46], ['P5', 26], ['P6', 13], ['P7', 28]]
```

Note that using a comprehension creates a *new* list and the original data will remain unmodified. If you want to modify the original in-place, it will be preferable to use a for-loop instead:

```
>>> for sublist in L:
...     sublist[1] -= 5
... 
>>> L
[['P1', 22], ['P2', 39], ['P3', 60], ['P4', 46], ['P5', 26], ['P6', 13], ['P7', 28]]
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer! Is there a way I can change this list comprehension from subtracting every value in the list to subtracting every value but the last one?

Comment: Well it's possible if your comprehension loops over indexes: for example [ [ L[i][0] , L[i][1]-5 if i<len(L)-1 else L[i][1] ] for i in range(len(L))] ; there may be simpler ways, but that's what came to my mind.

Answer (score 5):

As an example, this works:

```
Array1 = [['P1', 27], ['P2', 44], ['P3', 65], ['P4', 51], ['P5', 31], ['P6', 18], ['P7', 33]]

Array2 = [[i[0],i[1]-5] for i in Array1]

print(Array2)
```

Well, this is just a slightly different phrasing for the other answer :)

Answer (score 5):

For bigger lists, use numpy like this:

```
import numpy as np
data = [['P1', 27], ['P2', 44], ['P3', 65], ['P4', 51], ['P5', 31], ['P6', 18], ['P7', 33]]
a = np.array(data, dtype=object)

a[:, 1] = a[:, 1] - 5
```

a:

```
array([['P1', 22],
       ['P2', 39],
       ['P3', 60],
       ['P4', 46],
       ['P5', 26],
       ['P6', 13],
       ['P7', 28]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: An array with dtype=object is unlikely to be any better than a list.

Comment: Sure, you can set the dtype accordingly

Answer (score 3):

You can do with `map`,

```
l = [['P1', 27], ['P2', 44], ['P3', 65], ['P4', 51], ['P5', 31], ['P6', 18], ['P7', 33]]
result = list(map(lambda x:[x[0],x[1]-5], l))
```

Output:

```
[['P1', 22],
 ['P2', 39],
 ['P3', 60],
 ['P4', 46],
 ['P5', 26],
 ['P6', 13],
 ['P7', 28]]
```